# Encode a video in Windows Phone 8 with a stream of images

Tags: c++, image, windows-phone, video-processing

I'm really stuck and wanting to create a video with stream of Images.

I was looking at Microsoft Media Foundation to use the Sink Writer - IMFSinkWriter. 
Looks like IMFSinkWriter is not supported in Windows Phone 8.
From what I understand, MS Media Foundation API support is limited with Windows Phone.

Can this be done using the MS Media Foundation? or Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Thanks